# Sum multiple values from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to do an SQL query to get a sum number, but i don't know how to construct this query.

```
select count(*) from table1 where commom_fk in (1234);
select count(*) from table2 where commom_fk in (1234);
select count(*) from table3 where commom_fk in (1234);
select count(*) from table4 where commom_fk in (1234);
select count(*) from table5 where commom_fk in (1234);
```

I wanna to sum these results in just one query, is that a way to do this?

Thank you all.
-----*

This was answered.
But if i wanna to do this with more than one common_fk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT     
      ( SELECT ...)
    + ( SELECT ...)
    + ( SELECT ...)
    + ( SELECT ...)
    + ( SELECT ...)    
  AS sumAll
```

or to have all 5 results:

```
SELECT     
      ( SELECT ...) AS sum1
    , ( SELECT ...) AS sum2
    , ( SELECT ...) AS sum3
    , ( SELECT ...) AS sum4
    , ( SELECT ...) AS sum5
```